# How to fix the localhost/bWAPP/install.php error..?

Tags: kali-linux

I am getting this error while installing bWAPP:

[image: Error - bWAPP]

Answer (score 0):

Check of PHP installation by running this in terminal :

```
apt list --installed | grep "php"
```

if not installed then install it via :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php
```

Comment: tried it..
php is installed but it did not help to rectify the error